# Different model performance using LSTM keras sample_weight, when padding before or after the actual data

Tags: python, keras, padding, lstm

I am a building a model in Keras with input data X of variable length (N_sample, 50, 128). Each sample has 50 time-steps and at each time step, I have 128 features. However, I have used zero-padding to generate the input X, because not all Samples have 50 time-steps.

There are two ways of padding zeros.

1. For each sample, I feed the true data, say (20,128) in the beginning and then the remaining (30,128), I pad zero.
2. I pad the first 30 rows with zero and add data to the last 20 rows. 
   I then use `sample_weight` to assign a zero weight to the padded time steps.

However, in these two settings, I get completely different AUC on the test set. What happens if zero padded samples are fed before or after the true data in an LSTM network with `sample_weights`? Is it due to the initialization of the hidden state in the LSTM?

How would I know, which is correct? Thank you.

My model is as below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'), input_shape=(50, 128)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',sample_weight_mode='temporal', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=2, sample_weight=Sample_weight_train)
```

Comment: What's the result?

Comment: In pre-sequence padding, I get an AUC of 0.8. In post-sequence padding, I get an AUC of 0.67

Comment: @J.Adam, I'm trying to build a similar model with different sample length. But unlike you, I still haven't figured out pre-Sequence Padding. I would be eternally grateful if you could show me how you did that?